# How to query Salesforce Synonyms

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

Does anyone know how to query Synonym information?

Setup > Quick Find box > enter Synonyms > Synonyms

The documentation online is very sparse and does not provide any information on how to retrieve them. Also, it looks like synonyms are not taken into consideration during a SOSL search.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour].  Are you referring to [SynonymDictionary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_synonymdictionary.htm)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot query Synonyms in salesforce, Kindly upvote for this feature [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdmxMUAR/ability-to-do-soql-and-dml-on-synonyms).

Comment: The solution is to use SOSL. The synonyms are taken into consideration automatically via SOSL while searching. I still can not find what feature enables such behavior as it works in some org and not in others.